# rsync abborts with Error on sync from macOS to Synology NAS

Tags: macos, rsync

I like to sync my home-Folder from my Mac (10.15.7 ) to a mounted nas-Volume on my Synology with rsync.

My rsync-command running with my normal user:

```
rsync -PEav --info=progress2 --exclude '.DS_Store' --exclude 'Virtual Machines.localized'  --exclude 'Movies' /Users/myuser/ /Volumes/macosdata
```

It copied a lot. But it stops at some folders.

For example one error:

```
Documents/steuer/Version 2021/
      3,810,300   0%   14.63kB/s    0:04:14 (xfr#30, to-chk=0/115338)

sent 7,803,800 bytes  received 367,704 bytes  29,877.53 bytes/sec
total size is 315,968,495,287  speedup is 38,667.12
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1350) [sender=3.2.3]
```

The error 23 could point to wrong rights. So here the access-rights from the error-

```
Folder:
ls -All ~/Documents/steuer
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 itsme  staff  64 Jan 24 12:55 Version 2021
```

Infos about rsync:

```
rsync --version
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2020 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, hardlink-specials, symlinks, IPv6, no atimes,
    batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv,
    symtimes, no prealloc, stop-at, crtimes, file-flags
Optimizations:
    SIMD, asm, openssl-crypto
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
```

The NAS folder is mounted with:

```
//myuser@NAS.local/macosdata on /Volumes/macosdata (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by myuser)
```

Does anyone know the error and could give me a tip on how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Greetings

Chris

Comment: I have the same kind of problem trying to rsync from macos towards an ubuntu machine. The same rsync works fine towards Fedora boxes, not sure what is causing it, especially as it runs as root.